# Get two queries into same table (grouped by date)

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying my first select statements with an MySQL database and it's quite hard when you're not knowing what to google for.

So here's what I am trying to do, I have two queries:

```
select date(server_time) as d, count(*) as x
from table_A, table_B 
where date(server_time) >= '2015-07-17'  
and table_A.id = table_B.id    
and idname is not null
and idurl is not null        
group by date(server_time)
```

And

```
 select date(server_time) as d, count(*) as y
 from table_A 
 where date(sever_time) >= '2015-07-17'
 group by date(server_time)
```

What I am trying to achieve is to get both count-columns together with the dates:

```
d               x     y
-------------|-----|-------
2015-07-17   |  3  |  20
2015-07-18   |  2  |  50
2015-07-19   |  7  |  10
-------------|-----|-------
```

I have been playing around with `UNION`, `SELECT(SELECT count)` etc but no luck.

Comment: Please define `x` and `y` and also post the related table structures (`create table code`)

Comment: It can be easier to get an usefull answer if you output the actual results from both queries. Also consider using [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/). Btw I bet in `UNION ALL` =)

Comment: d first query gets me a table with the columns d and x, the second one with the columns d and y.. I just want to merge them together..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT date(server_time) AS d, 
       count(*) AS x,
       (SELECT y 
        FROM (SELECT date(server_time) AS d, 
                     id,
                     count(*) AS y
              FROM table_A 
              WHERE date(sever_time) >= '2015-07-17'
              GROUP BY date(server_time)) sub
        WHERE SUB.id = a.id) AS y
FROM table_A a
INNER JOIN table_B b ON a.id = b.id
WHERE date(server_time) >= '2015-07-17'
AND idname IS NOT NULL
AND idurl IS NOT NULL      
GROUP BY date(server_time)
```

Comment: @Kathi typo, try now

Comment: thanks, you forgot to also include `id` in the inner select, then it works like a charm!